# How do I change returnKeyType while editing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

How can I change the return key on the iPhone while it is editing. I know about

```
myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
```

However, this only works if I call `[myTextField resignFirstResponder];` then `[myTextField becomeFirstResponder];` which hides the keyboard then brings it back. Otherwise, it just stays as the one I had before, in this case it was "Go". I need to keep switching them depending on the characters the user enters.

---

In one line: How do I change the return key type of the keyboard while it is still editing?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`[textField reloadInputViews]` seems to do the trick...

Comment: Does the business. Key is to do things in the correct order, e.g.         [myTextField becomeFirstResponder];
myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
[myTextField reloadInputViews];

Comment: reloadInputViews has some caveats. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958427/can-i-change-property-uireturnkeytype-of-uitextfield-dynamically. It also changes the keyboard back to its initial state. So if the user had toggled to one of the other keyboard layouts (numbers, punctuation, etc), that state will get lost.

Comment: This will also break Keyboard Shortcuts on the device, i.e., if you call reloadViews while a user is editing (based on input changes) the shortcut popup will not appear; instead the text entered so far is selected. I would only use this in fields where shortcuts are disabled (e.g., password fields).

Comment: I've found if you change it during typing it will also break the autocorrect for the word that is currently being written.

Comment: Doesn't work in iOS 9.3 - but Peter's answer below works fine.

Comment: This works as expected on iOS 13.3 - keyboard state does not seem to get lost. Not done extensive testing yet.

Answer (score 6):

I found it a while back, forgot to post back here.
I am using:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: 
(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    [self performSelector:@selector(addressBarTextDidChange:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
    return YES;
}

-(void)addressBarTextDidChange:(NSString *)text {
    NSString *addressText = @"..."; //Wherever you get your text from... 
    if ([addressText isEqualToString:@""]==NO) {
        if ([addressText rangeOfString:@" "].location != NSNotFound) {
            //[addressBarTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeySearch];
            if (addressBarTextField.returnKeyType!=UIReturnKeySearch) {
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; //Setup the animation.
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0]; //The duration for the animation.
                [addressBarTextField resignFirstResponder];
                addressBarTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
                [addressBarTextField becomeFirstResponder];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            }
        } else {
            //[addressBarTextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyGo];
            if (addressBarTextField.returnKeyType!=UIReturnKeyGo) {
                [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; //Setup the animation.
                [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0]; //The duration for the animation.
                [addressBarTextField resignFirstResponder];
                addressBarTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyGo;
                [addressBarTextField becomeFirstResponder];
                [UIView commitAnimations];
            }
        }

    } else {
        if (addressBarTextField.returnKeyType!=UIReturnKeyDone) {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; //Setup the animation.
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.0]; //The duration for the animation.
            [addressBarTextField resignFirstResponder];
            addressBarTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            [addressBarTextField becomeFirstResponder];
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, I am animating the keyboard in and out for a duration of 0.0 seconds (so the user won't see it). I am also checking if the keyboard is not already the one I want before switching because constantly switching causes lag.

Answer (score 5):

In my case what it worked was the following:

```
sender.returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyNext;
[sender reloadInputViews];
[sender resignFirstResponder];
[sender becomeFirstResponder];
```

I had to force risignFirstResponder followed by a becomeFirstResponder.

Comment: Beware that this is flawed with a password field (secureTextEntry). Calling resignFirstResponder & becomeFirstResponder resets the field such that the next keyboard entry replaces the previous text (which is like the standard behavior on a password field).

Answer (score 2):

I made a custom Category to expose returnKeyType.
Just import and do `self.addField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;` or whatever you like to set as returnKeyType. You can also use it dynamically when the keyboard is already open. It will automatically refresh.

Here it is:

Interface:

```
/*

 Simple hack for exposing returnKeyType for UISearchBar without private APIs
 For you from CodeBuffet ;)


 Enjoy!

 ~PW

*/

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UISearchBar (ReturnType)

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) UIReturnKeyType returnKeyType;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "UISearchBar+ReturnType.h"

@implementation UISearchBar (ReturnType)

UITextField *textField;

- (UITextField *) traverseForTextViewInViews: (NSArray*) views
{
    // Traverse over all views recursively until we find the tresure TextField hidden deep the UISearchBar ocean!
    for(UIView *subView in views) {
        if([subView conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)]) {
            return (UITextField *) subView;
        }
        UITextField *tv = [self traverseForTextViewInViews:subView.subviews];
        if (tv) {
            return tv;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

#pragma mark Custom Setters & Getters

- (void)setReturnKeyType:(UIReturnKeyType)returnKeyType
{
    if (!textField) {
        textField = [self traverseForTextViewInViews:self.subviews];
    }
    textField.returnKeyType = returnKeyType;
    [self reloadInputViews];
    [textField reloadInputViews];
}

- (UIReturnKeyType)returnKeyType
{
    if (!textField) {
        textField = [self traverseForTextViewInViews:self.subviews];
    }
    return textField.returnKeyType;
}

@end
```

Comment: Amazingly, this still works in iOS 9.3. What you need to do is look for a subview that meets both UITextInputTraits (to set the returnKeyType) and UIResponder (so you can send reloadInputViews). You don't need to send reloadInputViews to 'self'. Also, you cannot write this all in Swift - there is no way to set returnKeyType (its an optional property) - at least for that alone you need to use Objective C. The nicest part of your solution is the keyboard does not move!

Comment: Unfortunately, after experimentation, I find I can go from say Default to Next - that works fine. But if the user deletes text, and I want to go back to Default, it doesn't "take" - it stays at Next (at least on the Simulator). Sigh. I was really hoping this would work all the time...

Comment: New problem - and a really serious one - so had to ditch this. If you specify a "NumberPad" keyboard, and use this trick, the keyboard gets "stuck" and won't dismiss - at least the keyboard image remains. Sigh. So switched back to the old "resign-become" technique.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with those 3 lines of code:

```
[sender setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[sender resignFirstResponder];
[sender becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: You need to deal with the keyboard getting dismissed then re-appearing. Not impossible but messy.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to update the returnKeyType (Next <--> Go) based on the current content of a textfield. The reloadInputViews method on the textfield did not work after setting the returnKeyType, alone.  As other posters have mentioned, a resignFirstResponder followed by a becomeFirstResponder was necessary. In my situation, when the textfield became the firstResponder and displayed the keyboard, it would animate the dismissal and reappearance of the keyboard.  On smaller devices or in landscape mode, it would also cause the view containing the textfield to jump momentarily. A solution that I have found to hide this unwanted behavior is to place the resignFirstResponder and becomeFirstResponder in a 0 second duration animation block.

```
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0
                                  delay:0.0
                                options:0
                             animations:^{
                                 [textField reloadInputViews];
                                 [textField resignFirstResponder];
                                 [textField becomeFirstResponder];
                             }
                             completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use TextField's delegate:

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
     textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySearch;
     return YES;
}

Comment: Yes but that still requires me to close and open the keyboard. I got the answer, so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

After changing `returnKeyType` of your `UITextField` or `UITextView` call:

```
textFieldOrView.resignFirstResponder()
textFieldOrView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Although calling `textFieldOrView.reloadInputViews()` works in some cases, it's not as safe as the solution above.